# How to get user id of logged in user

Tags: yii

I want to ask one question, that if I want to get the id of any user in `config/main.php` file of yii, then how can I get this ? If any one has idea please tell ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need it in `config/main.php`? You probably can't do that wit Yii way because it's not loaded yet at that moment. Explain an issue and maybe there is a better way to do that.

Comment: The config file should not contain data depending on the logged in user!

Comment: Which data? IMO config file isn't suitable place for such logic. Extending CWebApplication?

Comment: Actually I need language parameter dynamic into cofig file from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config/main.php is used to build your application, hence it is not possible to get data in there that is only available after Yii::app() is available.

But you can get your user id by `Yii::app()->user->id;`

You can use that everywhere, for example in Controller->init() that will execute before your SiteController is ran.

You can still set your language after you config.

```
Yii::app()->language = Helper::getLanguageFromUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
```

Ofc Helper is a fictive class here, it can be any thing. [See an example here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/26/setting-and-maintaining-the-language-in-application-i18n/)